# CIImage doesn't load into table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, filter, uiimage

I have a custom table view cell with an image view. I'm trying to load a `CIImage` into it. The code works when I load the `CIImage` into a regular image view on a blank storyboard (for testing the code), but for some reason, when I load the image into my table view cell, the image doesn't show up.

When I load a regular image from Assets into the table cell image view, that shows up. So it's just the `CIImage` that doesn't load into the table view cell.

Here's the code for my table view cell image. It takes a label, converts it to an image, and applies a blur to it. `messageLabel` is my `@IBOutlet` of the label on the table view cell:

```
func blurMessage() {
    let image = UIImage.imageWithLabel(label: messageLabel)
    let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    let imageToBlur = CIImage(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
    blurFilter?.setValue(imageToBlur, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    blurFilter?.setValue(4.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
    let outputImage: CIImage? = blurFilter?.outputImage
    blurredImageview.image = UIImage(ciImage: outputImage!)
}
```

When I run the app, the image is completely blank and doesn't show up.

Here's my cell in storyboard:

[image]

Is there a reason a regular image view would be loading in properly but a `CIImage` wouldn't be? Even when this exact code works in a blank storyboard? Is there a reason a `CIImage` won't load into a table view cell?

I call `blurMessage` in `viewDidLoad()` and it does run (it works when I test with a regular image, just not a `CIImage`)

Comment: What init is "UIImage.imageWithLabel(label: messageLabel)" ?

Comment: Your code is almost working, just change the init. Are you sure to call the  blurMessage() function?

Comment: Yeah I call the blurMessage function and it runs. It works when I use a regular image and not a CIImage. It's only the CIImage that doesn't work in the cell? Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Turns out because I had my label set to "isHidden" in storyboard, when I was taking an image of it in the extension from the label, it wasn't grabbing anything because it was hidden!